# Consequences of an intra-switch Loopback cable

Tags: switch, layer2, layer1, cable, loopback

I am using Dell switch and I looped it to itself. If I enable STP on 2 ports, what happen the port states?  I have attached the topology below.  Let me know, if you need clarification.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP5iV.png]

Comment: It probably isn't required, but it would be good if you can share the version of OS, and which specific PowerConnect hardware model you're planning to use.  I have done this with some powerconnects and they didn't exactly behave as a Cisco switch would.

Comment: PowerConnect 6248 and version: 1.0.0.27

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Because they have the same Bridge ID, the Port Priority will be used to determine which port to block, blocking the port with the higher Port Priority. In most STP implementations, the lower port, in this case port 1, will have a lower port priority unless port priorities are explicitly configured on the ports.